# How to write an ARRAY in a FOREACH loop with PHP for Wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops

I am new to arrays, and need a little help.

Basically what I want to do is to register menus on the go. So I made a loop that I thought would take care of that. Now the problem is that I don't really know how to register arrays properly.

```
$lim = array(); 

foreach ( $new_menus as $menu => $value ) {

    $rname = get_post_meta(1,"$menu",true);                 
    $slugpath = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '_', $rname );

    $lim[] = $slugpath => __( $rname );

    }
}
```

In the case above $slugpath would be header-menu and $rname would be Header Menu. Ultimately I want an array like the one below. How do I do this?

```
array(
  'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' ),
  'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu' ),
  'left-menu' => __( 'Left Menu' )
);
```

Comment: Unless your `$new_menus` array have it's values in keys, you should use `$value` var in `get_post_meta` function instead of key `$menu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should assign it to array like this:

```
$lim[$slugpath] = __($rname);
```

---

Additionally:

Unless your `$new_menus` array have it's values in keys, you should use `$value` var in `get_post_meta` function instead of key `$menu`, so it would look like this:

```
$rname = get_post_meta(1,$value,true);
```

And if you want `-` symbol in slugged text, you should replace `_` symbol in your `preg_replace` with it, and use `strtolower()` on it if you want it all lowercased:

```
$slugpath = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '-', $rname );
$slugpath = strtolower($slugpath);
```

Comment: Just an observation, we cannot pass `$variables` to `__()`, only literal strings.